# Create commands for displaying pictures from a list of files

Tags: macros, graphics, foreach

I have a lot of pictures to show in my document. My idea is to create one command per picture. So I try to use `foreach` command (maybe not the best for this...).

I store the filenames and the names I want as `newcommand` in a list:

```
\newcommand{\listPartDesign}{%
BOV_Esquisse/BOVEsquisse,%
Esquisse/Esquisse,%
BOV_Web/BOVWeb%
}
```

I use `foreach` for making a loop on these elements:

```
\foreach \fileCATIA/\nameCATIA in \listPartDesign {
\createCMDS{\fileCATIA}{\nameCATIA}
}
```

The `\createCMDS` will create the commands. I tried this (`\taille` is defined like this `\def\taille{1em}`):

```
\newcommand\createCMDS[2]{%
\expandafter\newcommand\csname #2\endcsname{\includegraphics[width=\taille]{BD_CATIA/PartDesign/#1.png}}}
```

I put the pictures in `./BD_CATIA/PartDesign`. The idea is to call a picture using for example in this case `\BOVWeb{}`. LaTeX says:

```
Undefined control sequence.
l.52         \BOVWeb
```

I think this is due to some expand problem but I don't find any solution for solving this. 
Another solution is maybe to use `\pgfkeys` but I am really not familiar with this.

Comment: You should say `\expandafter\gdef\csname#2\endcsname` instead of `\expandafter\newcommand\csname#2\endcsname`, because `\newcommand` only performs local definitions; `\foreach` does each cycle in a group.

Comment: @egreg And after, I can call the macro using the same syntax as a classical macro? I tried but it doesn't work: `#1` seems to be empty...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the usual problem that `\foreach` surrounds each cycle with `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`. Thus your `\newcommand` is lost as soon as the cycle ends.

You have to use `\gdef` for this, but actually `\xdef` is needed for expanding the local cycle variables. If you fear about redefining existing commands, you can use `\@ifdefinable`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\createCMDS[2]{%
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname #2\endcsname{%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname #2\endcsname{%
      \noexpand\includegraphics[width=\noexpand\taille]{BD_CATIA/PartDesign/#1.png}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

---

A different strategy with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\subscripttoken}{_} % small kludge

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newlist}{mm}
 {
  \clist_gclear_new:c { g_guuk_list_#1_clist }
  \clist_gset:cn { g_guuk_list_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\createcommandsfrom}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:cn { g_guuk_list_#1_clist } { \createcommand{##1} }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\createcommand}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_remove_all:NV \l_tmpa_tl \subscripttoken
  \cs_new_protected:cpn { \l_tmpa_tl }
   {
    \includegraphics[width=\taille]{BD_CATIA/PartDesign/#1.png}
   }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_remove_all:Nn { NV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newlist{PartDesign}{
  BOV_Esquisse,
  Esquisse,
  BOV_Web
}

\createcommandsfrom{PartDesign}
```

With this you don't need to remove manually the `_`; from `BOV_Esquisse` the macro name `\BOVEsquisse` will automatically be defined.

Comment: Too easy ( ;-) ), I forget about this thing... Thank you!!